# Get minimum y of a certain x in a region

Tags: regions

I have a region and a number x, and I would like to get the minimum y such that (x, y) is on the edge of the region. How can I do this?

For example, if I have the region `region = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}]]` and `x = 0`, I want the `y` such that `(x,y)` is a point at the bottom of the region.

Comment: I don't want to minimize any function. I just want to find, given an x, the y of the lowest point of the region. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Minimize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html) with a region constraint to find the point:

```
SeedRandom[1]
region = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}]]
```

[image]

```
sol = Minimize[
  {Indexed[x, 2], Indexed[x, 1] == 0},
  x ∈ RegionBoundary@RegionUnion@MeshPrimitives[region, 2]
  ]
point = x /. Last@sol
(* {-0.919228, {x -> {0., -0.919228}}} *)
(* {0., -0.919228} *)
```

[image]

Note how we used [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) to indicate that we want to minimize the second component of the position.

You will also notice that I'm using [`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html) and [`MeshPrimitives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshPrimitives.html) to convert the [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion.html) into a normal region. Originally, I was using `region` directly, but for some reason, a lot of the region functionality has huge problems with `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Alternatively, you could explicitly name both components of the position, giving the same result:

```
sol = Minimize[
  {y, x == 0},
  {x, y} ∈ RegionBoundary@RegionUnion@MeshPrimitives[region, 2]
  ]
point = {x, y} /. Last@sol
(* {-0.919228, {x -> 0., y -> -0.919228}} *)
(* {0., -0.919228} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find the minimum y at a certain x value (for example, 0). I tried adding a constraint to the minimize: `Minimize[{y, x == 0}, {{x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary@region}]`, but it's telling me `NMinimize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints`.

Comment: @user67077 Sorry, I read the question to quickly and completely missed that part - I have updated the answer to solve your actual problem. As you've noted, just adding the constraint does not work. Additionally, I had to convert the `BoundaryMeshRegion` into a normal region, see the answer for more details